# Exercise 0.1 of Rotman An Introduction to Algebraic Topology, Retract in Abelian Group

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I am a freshman in group theory and stuck in this simple question:

For abelian groups, one can prove that a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is a retract of $G$ if and only if $H$ is a direct summand of $G$; that is, there is a subgroup $K$ of $G$ with $K \cap H = 0$ and $K + H = G$.

In wiki there is the same statement (see the 1st property in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract_(group_theory)) but I cannot find proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decomposing an abelian group as the image and kernel of a retraction (Rotman 0.1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965530/decomposing-an-abelian-group-as-the-image-and-kernel-of-a-retraction-rotman-0-1)

Comment: In one direction, let $K$ be the kernel of the retraction. In the other, define the obvious projection.