# Kernel of the Reynolds operator

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose we have an action of finite linear group $G$ on finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over field $F$ of characteristic $0$. Now we define the Reynolds operator:

$$\rho(f) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} g(f)$$

where $f$ is some polynomial. The Reynolds operator is not a homomorphism of algebras since $\rho(fh) \neq \rho(f)\rho(h)$, but it is a homomorphism of abelian groups since $\rho(f+h) = \rho(f)+\rho(h)$ (since $G$ is linear). So now we can consider a ring of polynomials $R$ as a module over an algebra of invariants, and also consider an algebra of invariants $I$ as a module over itself. We get a homomorphism between modules $\rho \colon R \rightarrow I$.

I have information that $R$ can now be split as a direct sum $$R = I \oplus \ker(\rho) \,.$$

And I cannot understand why that is. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the Reynolds operator is that it makes things $G$-invariant: we have $g ρ(f) = ρ(f)$ for every $g ∈ G$.
And if $f$ was already $G$-invariant to begin with, then the Reynolds operator doesn’t change $f$: we have $ρ(f) = f$.

The image of $ρ$ is therefore precisely $I$, and the claim is that
$$
  R = \mathrm{im}(ρ) ⊕ \ker(ρ) \,.
$$

If $A$ is any abelian group and $e \colon A \to A$ is additive (i.e., a homomorphism of abelian groups), then the following conditions are equivalent:

- $A = \mathrm{im}(e) ⊕ \ker(e)$.
- $e$ is idempotent: $e^2 = e$.
- $e(x) = x$ for every $x ∈ \mathrm{im}(x)$.

The Reynolds operator satisfies the third condition, and therefore also the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So this deduction has more to do with the properties of abelian groups. Could you please explain how from (3) follows (1)?

Comment: Understood now, due to this question and answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965530/decomposing-an-abelian-group-as-the-image-and-kernel-of-a-retraction-rotman-0-1